# Firebase auth not working using Vue and Vuex

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex

I'm trying  to add authentication using Firebase in my Vue app, but I'm getting `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: _config_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.user.SignInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function"` error.
Here is my irebase config file:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "MY_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  databaseURL: "MY_DB_URL",
  projectId: "MY_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "MY_STORAGE_BUCKET",
  messagingSenderId: "MY_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "MY_APP_ID"
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Get a Firestore instance
export const user = firebase.auth();
export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Then the action in Vuex:

```
import { db, user } from "./config/firebase";

 loginUser({ commit }, payload) {
      user
        .SignInWithEmailAndPassword(payload)
        .then(user => {
          console.log(user);
          commit("SET_USER", user);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          commit("setLoading", false);
          commit("setError", error);
          console.log(error);
        });
      router.push("/");
    }
```

So far, I have been able to Create, Read, Update and Delete, although, the config file was slightly different than this, when I added `auth` was when I altered the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
user.SignInWithEmailAndPassword(payload)
```

into this:

```
user.signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload)
```

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#signinwithemailandpassword):

> Asynchronously signs in using an email and password.